# How to call and get the current device version?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am using  [this](https://gist.github.com/Jaybles/1323251) code to identify the iPhone Device. Can anyone explain to me how to call and get the current device version?

How to call one of these methods?

```
+ (DeviceHardwareSpecificPlatform)specificPlatform;
+ (DeviceHardwareGeneralPlatform)generalPlatform;
+ (DeviceHardwarePlatformType)platformType;
+ (NSString *)platformString;
```

I am calling them from another class.

Comment: do you need the version ? - `[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];`

Comment: The struct NSOperatingSystemVersion is available since iOS 8.0. Use it with NSProcessInfo's isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion:

Comment: i need device model like 6 or 6 plus  to set layouts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the link you gave, there is a usage.txt file

```
UIDeviceHardware *h=[[UIDeviceHardware alloc] init];
[self setDeviceModel:[h platformString]];
[h release];
```

Actually, it's an old piece of code with manually managed memory. With ARC, you may want to use:

```
UIDeviceHardware *h=[[UIDeviceHardware alloc] init];
[self setDeviceModel:[h platformString]];
```

Answer (score 0):

The UIDevice class provides all the information of the device on which your app is running.

UIDevice *deviceInfo = [UIDevice currentDevice];

```
NSLog(@“OS running on device: %@”, deviceInfo.systemName);
```

// OS running on device: iPhone OS
    NSLog(@“OS Version running on device:  %@”, deviceInfo.systemVersion);
  //OS Version running on device:  7.1
    NSLog(@“Device model:  %@”, deviceInfo.model);
  // Device model:  iPod touch

```
size_t size;  
sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);  
char *machine = malloc(size);  
sysctlbyname("hw.machine", machine, &size, NULL, 0);  
NSString *deviceModelVersion = [NSString stringWithCString:machine    encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];  
free(machine);  

NSLog(@"Device model version: %@", deviceModelVersion);  
//Device model version: iPhone4, 1  

NSLog(@“Device name:  %@”, deviceInfo.name); 
//Device name:  my iPod
```